# Flutter scrambling and translating the list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-bloc

I have a list and I want to mix these list elements randomly and put them in one of the two Text widgets, and the other one is translated using the translator package.How can ı do that?

```
List<String> wordsList = [
"abandon",
"ability",
"able"]

 return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: _screenHeight / 10,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Text("RANDOM WORD")),
                Text("TRANSLATION OF THE WORD"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: _screenHeight / 50,
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: I'd use .shuffle on the word list, then repeatedly .take(1) until empty.